# Is there a juju PostGIS charm out there?

Tags: juju, gis

I wonder if somebody has created if someone knows if exists a Postgis juju charm out there. Any help is very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There currently is no official PostGIS charm. However I was able to find this:

- http://code.scenzgrid.org/index.php/p/jujucharms/source/tree/f906376d2ecba34e82e15b1e558e1b9e3c4d4ea1/postgis/precise/postgis/README

I've mailed the author and asked him to submit it to the Juju Charm store. You can probably grab that charm by hand and either deploy it or derive from it to create a more complete charm.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I'll grab that one and see how it goes,  btw juju is awesome, kudos!